# Actual RSA encryption & decryption of strings?

Tags: encryption, rsa, padding

$K_{pub} = (n, e)$

$K_{pvt} = d$

Then

$E_{K_{pub}}(x) \equiv x^e \mod n$

Practically, when RSA is used to encrypt strings, what is the $x$ here? You cannot take it byte by byte because $\mod n$ will result in values larger than a byte. So what is done?

Comment: Practically RSA is not used to encrypt strings.

Comment: @Maeher - but it can be, right? So in case it needs to be done, how will it be done?

Comment: @Maeher - and even if it's used to encrypt an AES key - the AES key will be a 256 bit - i.e. 32 bytes. So how will it be encrypted - it can't be done byte by byte because `mod n` will result in values larger than a byte

Comment: What? Almost all encryption algorithms can be considered encrypting bit and bytes. Computationally, a string is a sequence of bytes. RSA keys are at least 1024 bits that make 256 bytes. What is your actual problem?

Comment: @kelalaka - I want to encrypt "ABCD". What would I raise to `e` to encrypt this? If I raise A (65) to the power `e` mod n, then the result wouldn't fit in a byte - so A encrypted may  take more than 1 byte. It may take upto n/8 bytes. So do I chop the string "ABCD" into n bit size blocks & then iteratively raise each block to power `e`?

Comment: Yout form an integer, possible big-endian style `65666769` then encrypt it of course using with a proper scheme like PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or OAEP

Comment: RSA implementations use big integers like GNU GMP, then you need to encode your message into a big integer that smaller than then the padding can support.

Comment: @kelalaka - you form a big integer from what? Each byte? Each set of bytes or what?

Comment: Read from here, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-7.2

Comment: @kelalaka - thank you. So the max length of the message which can be encrypted is (k-11) and the whole message is treated as one big integer. Is there no standard  scheme/algorithm where if the message is longer than (k-11), you treat it as multiple (k-11) size blocks & run the encryption on each (k-11) block? i.e. is it a hard limit - that the max size of message to be encrypted with RSA is (k-11)

Comment: It appears that you're expecting encryption to be format preserving. (An encrypted byte will again be a byte.) That is generally not the case. In fact any secure public key encryption scheme is necessarily randomized and thus always expanding.

Comment: RSA is not for encryption, rather signatures with RSASSA-PSS or key exchange with RSA-KEM.

Comment: @kelalaka - I understand - my final question was more theoretical than practical - so from you answer, I assume, RSA encryption for more than (k-11) size is not supported by any standard way. Thank you. If you can put your original comment(s) as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Well, for this kind of answer Maarten of Fgriue will be better, since they know the standards way better than me :)

Comment: @Maeher - no I am not expecting it to be format preserving. My question was more about a huge increase in size - i.e. if it's done byte by byte - then each byte would be turned into k bytes. However, from kelalaka's answer, it's clear it's not done byte by byte. But just 1 calculation with a hard limit on the size of the string to be encrypted.

Comment: I think this is a dupe of [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/42344/1172). I remember as I answered it :)

Answer (score 6):

> Practically, when RSA is used to encrypt strings, what is the $x$ in $x^e\bmod n$?

That depends on the variant of RSA. Among the most common:

1. Toy-sized textbook RSA, where the public modulus $n$ is small: it is customary to encrypt letter by letter (or pair of letters, as in the [original RSA article's *small example*](https://web.archive.org/web/20230318112554/https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf#page=10)) and concatenate the RSA cryptograms. Thus $x$ is the rank of the letters in the encoding used (or $x=x_0\,b+x_1$ where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are the ranks of two letters, with $b$ a public constant greater than the maximum value of $x_i$, e.g. $b=100$ in said article). There is no security for small $n$: a toy hammer won't actually nail. Small $n$ is anything up to like a hundred decimal digits. That can be factored quickly, which allows decryption. See this for [records](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982/555).
2. Textbook RSA with large $n$: it is customary to transform the string into bytes (e.g. per [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), the modern compatible superset of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)), then from bytestring to integer $x$ (usually per [OS2IP](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=8)). In Python

   ```
   int.from_bytes(bytes('François wears a !', 'UTF-8'), byteorder='big', signed=False)
   ```

   There is a size limitation to $k-1$ bytes, where $2^{8(k-1)}<n<2^{8k}$, which insures $0\le x<n$. On decryption, leading zero bytes are ignored/removed (due to the simplistic conversion from string to bytestring). Variations abound (some encoding of size to allow any bytestring, padding on the right so that $x$ is large even for small strings, [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)…).

   Caution: Textbook RSA in not secure under [Choosen Plaintext Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack):

   - An attacker can trivially verify a guess of the plaintext: just encrypt the guess and check against the cryptogram. That attack is devastating for names on the class roll, credit card number…
   - When short strings encode to small integers $x$, several other attacks apply, including

     - when $x$ happens to we writable as $x=x_a\cdot x_b$ for integers $x_a$ and $x_b$ small enough to be found by enumeration, there's a [meet-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack)
     - when $e<\log_2(N)/\log_2(x)$, it stands $x^e\bmod N\,=\,x^e$, and thus it's trivial to find $x$ by $e\text{th}$ root extraction.
3. [RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=23): similar to 2 plus random padding, and means to remove it on decryption. $x$ is a combination of the string to encode, 3 constant bytes, and at least 8 random (non-zero) bytes. The string is thus limited to $k-11$ bytes (per [§7.2.1 step 1](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=24)). This method is better, but still has serious defects:

   - Implementations of decryption are difficult to protect against side-channel attacks. The first was Daniel Bleichenbacher's *Chosen ciphertext attacks against protocols based on the RSA encryption standard PKCS #1*, in [proceedings of Crypto 1998](https://doi.org//10.1007/BFb0055716), and there are many variations.
   - Unless we lower the $k-11$ limit, encryption is inherently vulnerable to an attack under CPA costing $2^{63}$ encryptions.

   For these reasons, RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 should not be used in any new design.
4. [RSAES-OAEP](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=16): this is a major improvement of the above, using a hash. The string is transformed by the padding process into integer $x$ that is sort of random with $0\le x<2^{8(k-1)}$, and that's undone in decryption. Secure implementations of decryption are easier than for RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5. Security is theoretically reducible to that of the hash and of the RSA problem (finding a *random* $x$ given $x^e\bmod n$). The size limitation becomes $k-2h-2$ bytes (per [§7.1.1 step 1.b](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=23)) where $h$ is the size of the hash (e.g. $h=32$ bytes for SHA-256).
5. Hybrid encryption, e.g. [RSA-KEM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5990). A random value $x$ with $0\le x<N$ is RSA-encrypted with no padding, a symmetric encryption key is derived from that, and that key is used to encrypt(-and-[MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)) the string to encrypt. Some avenues of implementation mistakes on decryption that still exist in RSAES-OAEP are gone. Security is theoretically reducible to that of the encryption and the RSA problem, with a simpler proof and/or quantitatively better assurance than for RSAES-OAEP. There is no size limitation. However the size of the cryptogram is slightly increased, and we need a [Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) and an [authenticated cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), when that's built into RSAES-OAEP.

Comment: (cough) using the 8-bit bytes (formally octets) used by PKCS1 (and nearly everyone since about 1980) **SHA256 is 32 bytes**

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: thanks, sharp-eyed! Yes I no longer bother distinguishing a byte and an octet; I'm even sometime assuming a C char is a byte, and occasionally that INT_MAX is at least $2^{31}-1$. Where's that emphasis on portability that I once had?

Answer (score 0):

Composed the answer I was looking for from the different comments in response to the question

- Input is considered as an array of bytes/octets (8 bit).
- k is the octet length of the RSA modulus (n)
- Maximum number of octets which can be encrypted with RSA is `k - 11`
- The array of octets after padding is considered to be a Big Integer - `x`
- The Big Integer `x` is encrypted using the public key - $E_{K_{pub}}(x) \equiv x^e \mod n$

For more info, look at [OS2IP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-4.2) and [PKCS1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.2)

Comment: The method discussed in this answer is [RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=23), which has serious defects: implementations of decryption are difficult to protect against side-channel attacks; and (unless we change the $k-11$ limit) encryption is inherently vulnerable to an attack costing $2^{63}$ encryption under Choosen Plaintext Attack. For this reason the modern options are RSAES-OAEP (same ref), or hybrid encryption, e.g. [RSA-KEM](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5990).

Comment: @fgrieu - your comment is only as regards the padding, right? Overall, the encryption happens as said in the answer - except for the padding details?

Comment: What I had to say no longer fits a comment, so I made an [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87542/555).